# radio button.checkbox not visible inside table in materialize css

Tags: html, css, materialize

How can I include radio button or checkbox inside the table?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead><th>radio button</thead>
            <tbody><tr><td><input type="radio" value="r1"></td></tr></tbody>
        </table>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interesting find.  Remind me NOT to use that library as a default should not really hide things this way.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Well, Bootstrap does that too (it hides, i.e. the borders around fieldsets by default), so I'm afraid it's something we have to get used to.

Comment: @MrLister - borders and visual elements that were to the designer not aesthetically pleasing to me seem quite different than a functional input, I do see your point though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in F12 `opacity:0` what means your radio is invisible:

[image]

As [materialize doc](https://materializecss.com/radio-buttons.html) you have to use `radio` as below with `class="with-gap"`:

```
  <p>
    <label>
      <input class="with-gap" name="yourName" type="radio"/>
      <span>yout text</span>
    </label>
  </p>
```

**See working code**

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>radio button</thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>
              <label>
      <input class="with-gap" name="group3" type="radio" />
      <span>Red</span>
    </label>
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh, I see there are more requirements, such as the <span> after. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

Add the radio button as per the guidelines in materializecss. You can add the empty span if you don't need any label text.

```
<label>
        <input type="radio" />
        <span>label text</span>
</label>
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
                <thead><th>radio button</thead>
                <tbody><tr><td><label>
        <input type="radio" />
        <span></span>
      </label></td></tr></tbody>
        </table>
     </body>
    </html>
```